# Sending mail works from localhost but not from remote server

Tags: phpmailer

I have the last version of phpMailer (v.5.4.2).

This code sends mail from localhost, using XAMPP, successfully, but on the remote server (000webhost) it doesn't work.

Nothing happens, there is no error message, but simply there is no mail in my inbox, spam or trash folder.

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Username   = "qadenza@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "mypass";          
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;           
$mail->SetFrom('qadenza@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->Subject    = "My subject";
$mail->Body    = "My body";
$mail->AddAddress("qadenza@gmail.com", "Recipient name");
$mail->Send(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you contacted the hosting provider to check if they are blocking the outgoing ports or limiting sending through them?

Comment: XIII, No, this time I didn't contacted them, but a few months ago I successfully send mails from the same server. Unfortunately, I lost the scripts used.

Comment: I would really check with them, things are changing from time to time. This may be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453197/smtp-error-rcpt-not-accepted-from-server?rq=1